# Shorter way to assign emitted value to data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I pass my simple data from child to parent and I'm just wondering if I could omit to create a method for assigning this value to data? I would like to be able to assign it directly in the template.

My code is:

Child

```
<h1 @click="$emit('title', 'Home')" />
```

Parent

```
 <div @title="onTitleChange" />

onTitleChange(newTitle) {
  this.title = newTitle;
}
```

I would like to see something like this:

Child

```
<h1 @click="$emit('title', 'Home')" />
```

Parent

```
<div @title="title = value" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the emitted event’s value with `$event`. So, just a minor change in your parent.

```
<div @title="title = $event" />
```

**Reference:** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event